# Redirecting output of non pid 1 process to docker logs

Tags: docker, gelf

How to redirect logs of non pid 1 process to *dockerlogs* with ultimate goal of redirecting them to *gelf*?

There are 2 processes inside the *docker* container:

1) pid 1 process

2) non pid 1 process which writes to log file at *path*

Following [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)
And specifically

> The official nginx image creates a symbolic link from /dev/stdout to /var/log/nginx/access.log, and creates another symbolic link from /dev/stderr to /var/log/nginx/error.log, overwriting the log files and causing logs to be sent to the relevant special device instead.

didn't help.
Only *pid 1* process logs are redirected to *dockerlogs*

Performed steps:

1`ln -sf /dev/stdout _path_` in *Dockerfile*

2 Running the updated image as container.

3 `docker logs -f _containerid_`  shows only logs of *pid 1* process

There's [another official docker source](https://success.docker.com/article/Docker_Reference_Architecture-_Docker_Logging_Design_and_Best_Practices)

Which states

> Docker supports different logging drivers used to store and/or stream container stdout and stderr logs of the main container process (pid 1)

So it maybe the reason for not seeing the logs of non *pid 1* process.

Though, still don't understand why the created symbolic link by *ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/mysql/error.log* hasn't worked.

Answer (score 9):

I have same issue on the topic. The way I resolve it, you need to start the "ln -s" when docker is running **NOT** during Docker build (Dockerfile).

Here is my shell bash script

```
tail -n 0 -q -F /path/folder/*.log >> /proc/1/fd/1 &
```

Hope helps

Comment: Note that in a readonly container, you can not write to /proc/1/fd/1 - permisison denied :(

Comment: This worked perfect, even in K8s.  kubect exec -it ... and and if you do echo "hi" >> /proc/1/fd/1  it will send it to the container main process